# Join returning duplicates

Tags: sql, join

I keep getting duplicates on my join statement , any join experts please help I have been scratching my head for hours

```
SELECT  
  DISTINCT  
  image.ImageID,
  Lotpw.Lot,
  lot.Oper,
  lot.Product,
  lot.Process,
  Image.PartialWafer,
  image.UnitX,
  image.UnitY,
  Image.InspectionStation,
  Image.Status,
  Image.ImagePath,
  image.Date,
FROM Lot 
--FROM [VueDb].[dbo].[Lot] join [VueDb].[dbo].[LotPW] on lot.Lot=lotpw.Lot join [VueDb].[dbo].[Image] on lotpw.PartialWafer = image.PartialWafer 
  LEFT JOIN LotPW 
    on lot.Lot = lotpw.Lot  
  RIGHT JOIN image 
    on LOTPW.partialwafer = Image.partialwafer

WHERE (@Lot= '' or  Lot.Lot= @Lot)
  and (@Oper ='' or Lot.Oper= @Oper)
  and (@Product= '' or  Lot.Product= @Product)
  and (@Process= '' or Lot.Process= @Process)
  and (@PartialWafer= '' or  image.PartialWafer= @PartialWafer)
  and (@UnitX ='' or Image.UnitX= @UnitX)
  and (@UnitY= '' or Image.UnitY= @UnitY)
  and (@InspectionStation ='' or Image.InspectionStation = @InspectionStation)
  and (@Status ='' or Image.Status= @Status)
  and (@LossCode= '' or Image.LossCode= @LossCode)
```

[image]

below is an image of the output

Comment: Is this really the way you idented your query when you wrote it ? Also, you should provide the kind of output you want for your query..!

Comment: Are you really getting duplicates or maybe you misunderstand how DISTINCT works?

Comment: add lot.lot and LOTPW.partialwafer to your select, you might start to see why you get duplicates.

Comment: I suspect that `RIGHT JOIN` should actually be `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Agreed with @xQbert, you might even want to do a select *.  Sorting by ID and whatever key columns you have will make it easy for you to scan and see why you have duplicates.  For instance, you may have the ID twice, and in one column two different dates, or two different lots, or something.

Comment: Can you show us what you mean by duplicates?

Comment: i am getting the imageid ( which is unique i checked ) with  every lot  and PW combination so basically quadruple the results i expected

Comment: If a join is giving you multiple rows per relationship, it means you need to add more conditions to the join (usually).  Also, put as many conditions as possible in the `ON` clause.  Among other things, you won't always have a `LEFT JOIN` here - if you provide certain conditions, it'll turn into a regular `(INNER) JOIN`.  In addition, depending on RDBMS some of them perform really poorly at this pattern - the optimizer doesn't like them.  You may be better off using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a solution but might help)

Try this like Philip suggests and then inspect the data:

```
SELECT  
  *
FROM Lot 
  LEFT JOIN LotPW 
    on lot.Lot = lotpw.Lot  
  RIGHT JOIN image 
    on LOTPW.partialwafer = Image.partialwafer
```

I'm guessing you need to add other conditions into your `ON` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

From the way your query is setup, it looks like Lot is the top of the hierarchy, and has a 1:n relationship with LotPW (LotPW.Lot is suggesting the column:Lot is the PK on table:Lot, and thus the column:Lot is a FK on LotPW).  The left join suggest that you don't think each Lot row has a LotPW row (child) in the database.  This join will produce multiple rows any time there is more than 1 row in Lot which matches with LowPW.

The join to Image suggests that LotPW is the parent in this relationship, and that LotPW.PartialWafer is the PK on the LotPW table.  With this join being a Right Join to LotPW, it's saying that you don't believe that each PW has a parent.  This right Join should probably be a left join, otherwise you're negating the Left Join between Lot and LotPW

To de-dupe this, assuming multiple rows may be present in Lot or LotPW which match to a given PW, but you don't care about the extra data, do the join between Lot and LotPW and Group By on all values. Then use this resultset in the Left/Right Join with PW.

something like:

```
     Select distinct
        image.ImageID,
        Lotpw.Lot,
        lot.Oper,
        lot.Product,
        lot.Process,
        Image.PartialWafer,
        image.UnitX,
        image.UnitY,
        Image.InspectionStation,
        Image.Status,
        Image.ImagePath,
        image.Date
     From 
        (select Lot.Lot, Lot.Oper, lot.Product, lot.process, LotPW.PartialWafer 
            From Lot left join LotPW on Lot.Lot = LotPW.Lot
            Group by Lot.Lot, Lot.Oper, lot.Product, lot.process) UniqueLots
       Left Join Image on Image.PartialWafer = UniqueLots.PartialWafer
```

Answer (score 0):

Every row in your list is distinct; `select distinct` is a `row operator` meaning it works across the **entire row**. Notice (in yellow) that every row does have something different. pxq100 != pxq200 and so on.

[image]

So, if you have used `select distinct` and you think you still think you are getting duplicates then you just haven't used the right technique because [select distinct only does one thing](http://goo.gl/mHrCXo), you need `GROUP BY` or `ROW_NUMBER()`